# How to change blog.tags to become clickable images

Tags: shopify, liquid

I am looking to create clickable images, like clickable tabs on the blogs.liquid page that filters the page into relevant blogs categories/posts. Currently, the code below just lists the tags and filters correctly.

I have tried to assign an image to each category and while it shows, it is not clickable and therefore does not filter. My hope is to just have the image be clickable and then hide the text.

```
    <ul>
        {% for tag in blog.all_tags %}         
          {% if current_tags contains tag %}
              <li class="{{ tag | handleize }} current">{{ tag | link_to_tag: tag }} - current tag</li>
          {% else %}
              <li class="{{ tag | handleize }}">{{ tag | link_to_tag: tag }}</li>

                      {% if tag == 'cat1' %}
                          <img src="#1">   
                      {% endif %}
                      {% if tag == 'cat2' %}
                          <img src="#2">   
                      {% endif %}
                      {% if tag == 'cat3' %}
                          <img src="#3">   
                      {% endif %}

          {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
```

If any of you have any suggestions that will work on the Shopify platform I would be really grateful as I still haven't managed to work it out. I am using the Supply theme in case this is helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Silly me, if you just use the URL link that it triggers there is no need for liquid at all... e.g just link the a normal:

```
<a href="www.randomsite.com/blogs/education/cat1">
```

It will achieve the same thing.